# android full screen mode(ICS), first touch shows the navigation bar

Tags: android

In my video play app, I use this flag: `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` to make the navigation bar disappear, but when I touch the screen, the navigation bar appears, after the first touch, my touch events and other events work fine.

My question is how can I take over the first touch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't really take over the first event. You could implement [View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html) and be notified when the navigation bar is shown or hidden again, and then depending on its current state do what you wanted on the first touch, if possible.

However, there is no way you can completely take over the first touch, as stated in the documentation for [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION):

> There is a limitation: because navigation controls are so important, the least user interaction will cause them to reappear immediately. When this happens, both this flag and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN will be cleared automatically, so that both elements reappear at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this post, if your intention is to hide the navigation/status bar and not have it come back up when you touch the screen, take a look at the different "immersive" configurations as described here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

for example:

```
currentActivity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
```

That would effectively put your screen in "Full Screen" Mode regardless of any interaction the user has with the screen

To show the navigation/status bar again, simply change it back to:

```
currentActivity?.window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE
```